# Can not draw a shape in android, getting "ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument" error?

Tags: android

I am trying to draw circle in an android app which I am building using android studio.
Every time I run the code on my connected device, it shows a blank screen with no shape on it. It is a circle I am trying to draw. Actually a pie chart at the end. Neglect the constructor and setParts() method.
I am sharing the code. Please guide me regarding this problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    PieChartView pieChart;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new PieChartView(this));
    }

    public class PieChartView extends android.view.View{
        int totalNumberOfParts,unitPart,sections;
        int arrayLength;
        int[] arrayOfNumbers;
        public PieChartView(Context context){
            super(context);
            arrayOfNumbers = new int[10];
            arrayLength = 7;
            totalNumberOfParts = 0;
            unitPart = 0;
            totalNumberOfParts = 0;
            sections = 7;
            arrayOfNumbers[0] = 20;
            arrayOfNumbers[1] = 30;
            arrayOfNumbers[2] = 10;
            arrayOfNumbers[3] = 9;
            arrayOfNumbers[4] = 12;
            arrayOfNumbers[5] = 16;
            arrayOfNumbers[6] = 21;

        }
        public void setParts(int total,int numberOfSections){
            this.totalNumberOfParts = total;
            this.unitPart = 360/total;
            this.sections = numberOfSections;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            System.out.println("Entered onDraw method");
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            canvas = new Canvas();
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
            int color = Color.parseColor("red");
            paint.setColor(color);
            canvas.drawCircle(5,5,10,paint);
           /* float initialAngle = 0f;
            int i=0;
            int j=0;
            int k =1;
            int x =0;
            int con = 90;
            int red = 7;
            int green =0;
            int blue= 0;
            int colorindex = 0;
            String[] hexStringColorArray = {"#808000","#808080","#800000","#C0C0C0","#000000","#FFFFFF","#FF0000","#00FF00","#0000FF","#FFFF00","#00FFFF","#FF00FF"};
            while(i<sections){
                System.out.println("entered");
                RectF rect= new RectF(50f, 50f, 100f,100f);
                canvas.drawArc(rect,initialAngle,(unitPart*arrayOfNumbers[i]),true,paint);
                initialAngle+=unitPart*arrayOfNumbers[i];
                i++;
                System.out.println("loop complete");
                //System.out.println("i = "+i);
                //System.out.println("j = "+con*j);
                // System.out.println("k = "+con*k);
                //System.out.println("hexStringColorArray[colorindex] "+hexStringColorArray[colorindex]);
                //colorindex+=1;
            }*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you have this  `canvas = new Canvas();` in onDraw?. You already have the canvas right?

Comment: yeah right...let me remove...

Comment: well... it worked,Thanks.... Can see the circle...But the error remains...

Comment: i cannot see anything wrong apart from the one i already mentioned